# Oxford MAT functional equation question

Tags: contest-math, functional-equations

Here is the Oxford MAT 2014 question 1. J). The problem is to find $\int_{-1}^1 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $ given that f(x) satisfies

$ 6+f(x)=2f(-x) +3x^2 \int_{-1}^1 \! f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t. $

for all real x. The examiners solve the problem by integrating the above identity from 1 to -1, giving

$ 12+  \int_{-1}^1 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x  = 2 \int_{-1}^1 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x +[x^3]^1_{-1} \int_{-1}^1 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x $.

Noting that $\int_{-1}^1 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x=\int_{-1}^1 \! f(-x) \,\mathrm{d}x$ as reflecting the function in the y-axis does not change the area between the function and the x-axis. They then continue by substituting $A=\int_{-1}^1 \! f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ and solving the resulting linear equation for A.

Now I do not understand what happens in line 2 with the original equation. More specifically what happens to $\int_{-1}^1 \! f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$? Thanks for any help! I would also appreciate if you could direct me to similar questions, thanks!

Comment: Is the answer 4?

Comment: @John Lou Yes, the answer is four. If you didn't know you can find the paper with solution on the oxford homepage.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look it up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind that $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt$ is a constant because the integral is given numberical bounds.

This means that $\int_{-1}^{1}f(t)dt$ is analogous to $\int_{-1}^{1}f(x)dx$

Thus, when integrating the whole thing, you treat that part as a constant, which remains the same after integration.

Comment: If the integral is a constant shouldn't it remain in the equation. But it seems to me that it just vanishes.

Comment: OK it has just clicked for me. Thanks! Just one more question: Why do they use a variable in t and not in x? To confuse students like me? Also do you know any where I can practice this type of question or do you know a key term I can search under? Thanks

Comment: @wittbluenote So long as there is an "active" $x$ in the equation, it would be a mistake to call anything else $x$, even if it is a "dummy" variable liek the $t$ in the integral. After the integration, all the variables are "dummies" and can be safely called the same thing

Comment: Are you applying to Oxford to take the MAT? Oxford's website has some good resources, and STEP resources can be found elsewhere (a harder Cambridge version of the MAT).

Comment: @ Nick Pavlov I see! thanks

Comment: @Harry Alli Yes I am applying to Oxford this year. I have done some step papers... Actually thought they were easyer! I was realy just looking for some good practice problems specifically on these types of functional equations.

Comment: @wittbluenote You could extend the problem to finding an explicit expression for $f(x)$

Comment: @NickPavlov Nice idea! Isn't that straightforward though? Once one knows that f(x)=f(-x) (?) and one knows the vaue of integral one has a linear equation is terms of f(x). Am I right?

Comment: @wittbluenote Yes. But does one know that? (Yes, one does, once one proves it).

Comment: @NickPavlov Actually I think there is a different way. Letting $x\rightarrow -x$ one has a new equation in f(x) and f(-x). One can eliminate f(-x) and use the value of the integral previously calculated to find f(x). Anyway thanks for your help and answering my questions!

Comment: @wittbluenote Exactly. And in the process, you prove that $f(x) = f(-x)$. Note that the official solution you presented initially didn't prove (or claim) that $f$ is an even function, only that the integral is not affected by the reflection. The former is a stronger statement. Sorry Harry Alli for hijacking your answer's comment section, this was the last one, I promise.